# Python. How do I check if the current value is greater, the same, or smaller than the previous?

Tags: python, while-loop

Still pretty new to Python. My program needs to check if the current number is the same as the previous number inputted. It has to make no response at all to the very first number and there should be at least two numbers in the input. So far, I have come up with this - I can check against the first number but not the current number - I feel I'm missing something obvious here. Thanks for the help.

```
f_n = 0
n_n = 0

print('Enter the first number: ' , end = ' ')
fn = input()
f_n = int(fn)

finished = False
while not finished:
    print('Enter the next number, 0 to finish: ' , end = ' ')
    nu = input()
    n_n = int(nu)
    if n_n != 0:
        if n_n == f_n:
            print('Same.')
        elif n_n > f_n:
            print('Up.')
        elif n_n < f_n:
            print('Down.')
    else:
        finished = True
```

Comment: let me get this straight, you want to take 2 numbers from the user, return true if they are the same?

Comment: What is current number? is it f_n or new input which in nu?

Comment: In the loop, you want to check the users input against the previous input? If so, update - `f_n = n_n` - at the *bottom* of the while loop.

Comment: Protip: You can replace `print(some_message)` followed by `input()` with just `input(some_message)`.

Comment: Protip : using meaningful names makes your code _much_ easier to understand. `fn`, `f_n`, `nu` and `n_n` are totally meaningless - even if you know what they are supposed to mean, you have to make a mental effort to remember each time you see one of them, and this distracts you from understanding what the code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me get this straight: you want to check that the input in the while loop is only compared against the latest value inputted. If this is the case, all you've got to do is add a single line:

```
f_n = 0
n_n = 0

print('Enter the first number: ' , end = ' ')
fn = input()
f_n = int(fn)

finished = False
while not finished:
    print('Enter the next number, 0 to finish: ' , end = ' ')
    nu = input()
    n_n = int(nu)
    if n_n != 0:
        if n_n == f_n:
            print('Same.')
        elif n_n > f_n:
            print('Up.')
        elif n_n < f_n:
            print('Down.')
        f_n = n_n # Add this line!
    else:
        finished = True
```

Comment: Thanks musikreck - I hope the more practice I do the easier it becomes.

Comment: Of course. Just gotta take a moment to step back from the screen and think about what needs to happen in your program once in a while :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed assigning the new number to the current number (since the newest will become the old and you will re read a new number). Some side notes, you don't need to cast your input since python will do that for you, you can use

```
input("message") #instead of 
print("message") 
new = input()
```

Small last remarks, you don't need to initialize ints ( f_n =0) and it's better to name the param to what you are going to need it for, f_n nn and stuff like that are not as clear when you want to re read your code (or if someone else trying to read it)

```
oldnb = input("Enter the first number")
finished = false

while not finished:
    newnb = input("Enter the next number, 0 to finish: ")
    if(newnb == 0)
        finished=true
    else 
        if newnb == oldnb
            print("Same")
        elif newnb>oldnb
            print("Up")
        else
            print("Down")
```

Comment: Thanks bleh - I must remember to check the small details.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = int(input('enter the first number: '))
finish = False
while not finish:
    num2 = int(input('enter the next number: '))
    
    if num2!=0:
        if num1 == num2:
            print('same')
        elif num1<num2:
            print('up')
        elif num1>num2:
            print('down')
        num1=num2

    else:
        finish = True
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).